# client.user is null in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I need to edit the last message from my bot but `client.user` is null. I logs bot before starts `run(msg)`
It's my code:
command:

```
const client = new Client();
module.exports = {
  name: "work",
  description: "komenda na pracę",
  aliases: ["praca"],
  guildOnly: true,

  run(msg) {
    const { channel } = msg;
    channel.send("test")
    client.user.lastMessage.edit("test2")
  },
};
```

error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastMessage' of null
```

Comment: It looks like that's a new client, not the one already logged in in your other file where this module is imported. Maybe try to pass the `client` to your `run()` method.

Comment: I believe you have to use client.login(token) before being able to access client.user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a new Client for your 'work' module. As statted in [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser), client.user is defined after the client was logged in. In your case, the client isn't so that's why you are getting `undefined`.
However, I believe you wanted to use an already logged-in client. Therefore, you have to import it.
For example, you'd need something like that

```js
// index.js
const client = new Client()
client.login(token)
+ module.exports = client;

// work.js
const client = require('./path/to/index.js');
[...]
```

Comment: It doesn't work probably because I am stupid and I cannot export client.login(token)